# ejabberd consume too much memory when announce all

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

When I send message to mydomain/announce/all, I get the following errors, and the message is not sent.

```
(ejabberd@localhost) The process <0.20027.1> is consuming too much memory:
[{old_heap_block_size,45988046},
{heap_block_size,22177879},
{mbuf_size,0},
{stack_size,19},
{old_heap_size,35268382},
{heap_size,7381863}]
[{current_function,{lists,reverse,1}},
{initial_call,{erlang,apply,2}},
{message_queue_len,99477},
{links,[<0.20030.1>]},
{dictionary,[]},
{heap_size,22177879},
{stack_size,17}]
```

What's problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message come from a debug module, used to troubleshot memory issue when developing ejabberd module.
I do no think you should worry about it. Probably, you should not even run watchdog in production.